# RoR undefined method `attr_accessible' after any code edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, plugins, activesupport

I'm implementing a great plugin I found for awarding points/badges/ranks to users based on user behaviors.  It is called Merit and can be found here: https://github.com/tute/merit

I have two models: "Post" and "Tag".  Associations are: posts have many tags, tags belong to a post.

I am awarding points to users when they create a "Post."  I configure the plugin to award points whenever the "create" action of the posts controller is called.

**The problem:**

When I start the server, I go through my flow for creating a new post with any associated tags.  This works perfectly.  It will work perfectly until I edit my code (in controller or model) in any way. After the edit, when trying to create a new post, I will get this error:

```
undefined method `attr_accessible' for Merit::Action:Class
```

It doesn't seem to matter what kind of edit I make, as long as I change the fundamental content of the file (this includes simply adding a debug "puts" statement).  At this point, I can no longer create posts at all, as every attempt to create a post will result in the same error.  Then, once I restart WEBrick, it will work again (until I edit code again).

**What is happening here?**  Howcome the simple act of editing my code causes attr_accessible to suddenly become undefined in the Merit plugin until I restart my server?

Comment: Are you using rails_admin? I had the same problem with rails_admin

Comment: No, I'm not using rails_admin.  How did you solve yours?

Comment: My problem was visiting /admin would bring up that error. I added config.excluded_models << "Merit::Action" in my rails_admin initializer but this doesn't apply to you.

Comment: which rails version are you using? 

I think the author moded `merit` to support Rails4. Hope you are aware that Rails4 doesn’t support `attr_accessible` any more and uses [strong parameters](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters) instead.

If this is a rails3 project, either upgrade your rails version to 4 or using `protected_attributes` gem should fix it temporarily.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a ruby class reload issue.

I think your plugin is not being reloaded along with the files you change, so the gem's behaviour is not re-injected into the new code. When you restart the rails server the app's code and the gem's code are in sync and gem's behaviour can be injected in app's code.

Does it make sense?